# Заполнение базы(Django, SQL)

Tags: python, django

ребята, изучаю django и дошел до полей M2M,OTO,FK и застрял, я пытаюсь заполнить базу, все вроде работает, но есть промежуточное поле

```
authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

*book_authors* и эта таблица пустая, читал документацию, не помогло))

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pubdate = models.DateField('date published')


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from annotate_aggregate.models import Author, Publisher, Store, Book

admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Book)
admin.site.register(Store)
```

management/commands/seed.py

```
import random
from django.utils import timezone
from annotate_aggregate.models import Author, Book, Store, Publisher
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('arg', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        num = options['arg']

        for _ in range(int(num)):
            Author.objects.create(name=fake.name(), age=random.randint(20, 70))

        for _ in range(int(num)):
            Publisher.objects.create(name=fake.company())

            for publisher in Publisher.objects.all():
                for _ in range(int(num)):
                    books = [Book(
                        name=fake.sentence(),
                        price=random.uniform(29.99, 225.9),
                        pages=random.randint(50, 300),
                        rating=round(random.uniform(1, 5), 2),
                        pubdate=timezone.now(),
                        publisher=publisher)]
                    Book.objects.bulk_create(books)
        books = Book.objects.all()
        for _ in range(int(num)):
            store = Store.objects.create(name=fake.company())
            store.books.set(books)
            store.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) к `ManyToMany` полю я не нашел метода `bulk_create()`. Добавление элемента осуществляется при помощи метода `add`.

```py
Author.objects.add(authors[0], authors[1], authors[2])
```

Возможно, что лучше будет циклом.

```py
for item in authors:
    Author.objects.add(item)
```

К сожалению, не могу сказать насколько это решение объективно хорошее с точки зрения производительности и ресурсов. Но оно работает

Comment: Предполагаю, что первый вариант все же лучше) `ManyToMany` связь "под капотом" предполагает создание дополнительной таблицы связей, куда и вставляются связи (1 строка = 1 связь), думаю разработчики Django не глупы, и вставку нескольких элементов делают одним запросов в базу, а в цикле кол-во запросов = кол-во элементов. Но лучше кнчн посмотреть код)

Comment: Чтобы уменьшить кол-во запросов, используются транзакции `django.db.transaction` (вроде путь верный)